# How to clone SSH GitHub Repo in VS-Code DevContainers during build phase

Tags: git, docker, visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-devcontainer

I am trying to create a VS Code dev-container for a project my team is working on which requires pip installing a private package from private GitHub repository. I removed pip from the following problem statement because the problem is the same with a simple `git clone` statement and less complex to use git as an example instead of Python.

Basically, all I want to do is clone a repository in the docker build step via SSH using something similar to the following Dockerfile:

```
ARG VARIANT=3-bullseye
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/python:0-${VARIANT}

# =================================================================================================
# Setup Git and SSH
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends git git-man man openssh-client less && \
    rm -r /var/cache/* /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Download public key for github.com
RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

# Clone the repo
RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone git@github.com:Private/foobarbaz.git
```

```json
{
    "name": "Python 3",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
        "context": "..",
        "args": {
            // Update 'VARIANT' to pick a Python version: 3, 3.9, 3.8, 3.7, 3.6.
            // Append -bullseye or -buster to pin to an OS version.
            // Use -bullseye variants on local on arm64/Apple Silicon.
            "VARIANT": "3.10-bullseye"
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
            "bash": {
                "path": "/bin/bash"
            }
        }
    },
    "extensions": [
        "ms-python.python",
        "ms-python.vscode-pylance",
    ],
    "mounts": [
        "source=/var/run/docker.sock,target=/var/run/docker.sock,type=bind",
        "source=/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock,target=/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock,type=bind,consistency=cached",
    ],
}
```

If I were to build this image outside of vscode I would reference the [Using SSH to access private data in builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds) and do something similar to `docker build --ssh default .` but it appears VS Code dev-containers doesn't support this and I believe it is related to [Buildkit support at devcontainer.json level](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1409).

I can kinda pull this out into a shell script and run it under `postCreateCommand` but I would prefer to have it in the Docker image so the image can be cached and the IDE can start up faster without waiting for the git clone.

I have tried to find an example of someone who has done this but most examples I found are on how to mount SSH when the dev-containers is in the `run` phase, not the `build` phase.

**Note**: my goal is to use SSH, not pass HTTPs username and password credentials via build params.

Comment: Interesting. I never think of this way. I usually git clone the repo and the repo contains the `.devcontainer` folder. I just run `devcontainer open .` in the the repo directory.
The src code is volume mounted in the devcontainer.

Comment: @ikhvjs technically the goal is to clone a different repository than the one being worked on. I.e. `pip install git+git://github.com/mozilla/elasticutils.git`. I believe most people that use `devcontainer` have it as part of the source code and use it like that (even we use it like that). This is a different usecase.